# Parse picture from HTML in Objective-C 

Tags: html, objective-c, image, parsing

I am trying to retrieve the image from this html data:

```
<div class="image">
 <a href="http://www.website.com/en/105/News/10217/">
   <img src="/images/cache/105x110/crop/images%7Ccms-image-000005554.gif" 
        width="105" height="110" alt="kollsge (photo: author)" />
 </a>
</div>
```

This is my code:

```
HTMLNode *bodyNode = [parser body];

NSArray *imageNodes = [bodyNode findChildTags:@"div"];

for (HTMLNode *imageNode in imageNodes) {
    if ([[imageNode getAttributeNamed:@"class"] isEqualToString:@"image"]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [imageNode getAttributeNamed:@"img src"]);
    } 
}
```

Help would be much appreciated.

I solved it by this code:

```
 for (HTMLNode *imageNode in imageNodes) {
        if ([[imageNode getAttributeNamed:@"class"] isEqualToString:@"image"]) {
            HTMLNode *aNode = [imageNode firstChild];
            HTMLNode *imgNode = [aNode nextSibling];
            HTMLNode *imNode = [imgNode firstChild];
            NSLog(@"%@", [imNode getAttributeNamed:@"src"]);
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging with step through?

Comment: Is this for a plugin? Are you after only the image's URL/`href` attribute value? Why don't you attach it to a DOM node and extract it from there? EDIT: Or maybe it's Objective-C for iOS?

Comment: I am just trying to get the url of the image to put in the cell. I managed to put title and content of the data but can't do anything with photos..

Comment: You're not giving enough information; what is the problem? Do you understand the code? Is this line: `NSLog(@"%@", [imageNode getAttributeNamed:@"img src"]);` logging the `img src` value? Are you trying to get the `img src` value into a variable and you don't know how? What cell? You gotta explain what's going on and what you are after in enough detail so we're not all left guessing.

Comment: I assume you're using libxml2, which would be useful information. I would guess that getAttributeNamed:@"img src" is not the correct way to get that piece of data. You need to get the img node then get its src attribute.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to see img src value in the console. Afterwords I know how to deal with it. Thanks.

Comment: And you're not seeing the `src` value in the log? Is that the problem? Have you tried `[imageNode getAttributeNamed:@"src"]` instead of `[imageNode getAttributeNamed:@"img src"]`? Note, I removed the `img` from the first.

Comment: I guess you're not going to volunteer any potentially helpful information, such as errors, or whatnot. Last guess I have is that `getAttributeNamed:@"img src"` maybe should be `getAttributeName:@"src"` or `getAttributeName:@"img src"`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028759/objective-c-passing-a-variable-to-another-ibaction

Comment: I am using Ben Reeves' HTMLParser. It worked great with regard to any texts but I cannot figure out how to deal with photos. It just says null. There are no errors. https://github.com/zootreeves/Objective-C-HMTL-Parser

Comment: Git is cool and all, but their code system seriously annoys me because it's so hard to search. If you know a technique, I'd appreciate the tip. I searched for a good thirty minutes straight for those functions, never found that project. Jeez.

Comment: I never search anything on Git, because I have the same problem with finding things. I just end up there through searching on other websites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not going through the tree correctly.  You are attempting to find an attribute named **img src** on your **div**.  That would look like this:

```
<div class="image" img src="whatever">
```

For one thing, that's not valid HTML, but the more important issue is that you want to be looking at the *children*.  The thing you are looking for is nested inside the div, not an attribute.  Since your div only has one child, a quick look at the project you provided in the comments leads me to believe that the following will work:

```
HTMLNode *bodyNode = [parser body];

NSArray *imageNodes = [bodyNode findChildTags:@"div"];

for (HTMLNode *imageNode in imageNodes) {
    if ([[imageNode getAttributeNamed:@"class"] isEqualToString:@"image"]) {
        HTMLNode *aNode = [imageNode firstChild];
        HTMLNode *imgNode = [aNode nextSibling];
        NSLog(@"%@", [imgNode getAttributeNamed:@"src"]);
    } 
}
```

Comment: On which line ?  Saying it has a bad access code is the same as simply saying "It didn't work"  I'm sure my theory is correct though, you need the children, and not the attribute of div.

Comment: HTMLNode.m file  for(xmlAttrPtr attr = node->properties; NULL != attr; attr = attr->next)

Comment: Your code helped me to solve the problem I had with getting href though. Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps the image is a sibling of the a and not a child.  Kinda makes sense...I will edit my answer above.

Comment: I used the exactly the same code and it shows me the link. It is not location of the image though. Anyway, I will consider it as answered. If you have any other advice, I will appriciate. Thank you, once again.

Comment: I thought that didn't look right. I wonder why they decided to use `getAttributedNamed()`, with a `d` on the end? How clunky.

Comment: I agree, but this is the only htmlParser that I could use. Others are too hard for me to understand.