# Picture too big in iPhone WebView...Scales To Fit Not An Option

Tags: iphone, html, regex, uiwebview, uiimage

I am working on a blog app.  I parse the RSS feed and then take one of the item elements and build `html` string.  I have to leave the `UIWebView` Scales To Fit turned off, or the text all gets shoved into one page, and is too small to read.  If I turn on scales to fit on the `UIWebView`, the text is perfect, but if larger pictures are in the blog, they stretch well off the `width` of the page.  One such picture is

```
img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-4532" title="Father_and_daughter_1" 
src="http://treymorgan.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Father_and_daughter_1.jpg" alt="" 
width="590" height="342" /
```

In this case, the width goes well beyond 320px.  Is there any way I could use `regex` or something to detect if the width is greater than 320, and if so, have it replace the `width` and `height` by something that would fit?

Comment: I hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10956819/parse-picture-from-html-in-objective-c) helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem comes from the view port. You should have a look to the [apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html).